# Can't remove dotNET Runtime 2.1.17

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, windows-10, uninstallation

I have a vulnerability scanner that returns a finding for an outdated dotNET build - 2.1.17.  This needs to be removed.

I have confirmed the file is in the right spot (C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All\2.1.17) and I have deployed the updated version "2.1.25".

Unfortunately, 2.1.17 refuses to be removed - the latest dotnet-core-uninstall tool does not list it as an option, and it doesn't let me just hand-jam 2.1.17 as an -aspnet-runtime option either.

Somewhere on the 'net I found a suggestion that if I remove a certain SDK installation (5xx something - naturally can't find it again) that it would also remove the files.  It didn't, and 2.1.17 is still there.

I also tried simply taking ownership of the directory in Windows and then removing it with RMDIR.  The directory *was* removed and all the files were gone, but when I rebooted it looks like it was actually restored and now I'm stuck with 2.1.17 again.

I'm no Developer, so my experience with these packages is in deploying and removing them, which I've done successfully in the past either by deleting the folder (for a very old version) or this dotnet removal tool.  I've not had the Runtime simply just not be removable.

Is there a way to get rid of these Runtimes without the dotnet tool?

EDIT: I followed Ian Kemp's advice below and it did briefly remove the 2.1.17 folder that was behind my finding, but it actually restores when the machine is rebooted (causing it to be flagged again).

Comment: Is Visual Studio installed on the computer?

Comment: Ian, it is - in fact, several versions are installed (2015, 2017, 2019).

Comment: Well, there's likely your problem - VS 2019 depends on Core if certain workloads and/or ocmponents are installed. Run the Visual Studio Installer to check that (click Modify > Individual components, check if any of the .NET Core components are checked). If they are, then the actual problem is that you need to update VS 2019 to the latest version (16.9 at this time), which will replace the vulnerable runtime version with the most up-to-date one. But I have to ask, why are you doing any of this if you're not a developer?

Comment: Looks like these are installed:

.NET Framework 4.5.2 targeting pack
.NET Framework 4.8 targeting pack
.NET Framework 3.5 development tools
.NET Framework 4.6.1 SDK
.NET Framework 4.6.2 SDK
.NET Framework 4.7 SDK
.NET Framework 4.7.1 SDK
.NET Framework 4.7.2 SDK

PART 1 / 2

Comment: I am doing this because I'm the admin for the network - in the past, this was delegated to the Developer, but COVID has them working remote, away from this machine (indeed recent changes to security posture on the network probably means I will need to do the actual management going forward).  I'm held to task to remediate this vulnerability by an outside auditing group.

Seems you were right on the money; now that VS is updated it seems to be fixed.Oddly that was my first action and 2.1.17 did not go away then (one or two weeks ago).  PART 2 of 2.

Comment: AH, I spoke too soon!  I rebooted the machine after said update, ran the scanner, and it looks like the folder actually repopulated itself!

Comment: Seems the finding is now actually in the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\2.1.17 folder now, actually.  Removing .NET 2.1.813 on a guess didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to remove the 2.1.813 SDK, then manually TAKEOWN and RMDIR the offending directories, then reinstall 2.1.813 SDK.